# How do you hyperlink text in vim editor?

Tags: vim

I need to set some text to be hyperlinked to a website via the vim editor.  How do I accomplish that?

Comment: ... *what* is it that you actually want to do now?

Comment: Again, I just need to hyperlink some text in the vim editor.

Comment: Is this a thing you've seen done? How would you expect to launch the link?

Comment: The txt file will be used elsewhere. Opening the link from within vim is not necessary. I just need to know how to create a hyperlink in vim.

Comment: txt files don't have hyperlinks.

Answer (score 4):

Vim is not a word processor. Vim displays text *exactly* as it is on the disk. You can do *some* minor "formatting" of text such as folding lines, syntax highlighting, concealing a few characters, but that's it. None of this information is actually stored in the file itself, instead, it is applied from "outside the file" with Vim. This is different from `.doc` files, where the formatting is stored *in the file*.

Note that [`gx`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw%2dgx) opens links. Perhaps this is what you want?

What you want can maybe be done with:

- A [`conceal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3asyn%2dconceal) pattern combined with some custom mappings. I haven't tried doing this, but it's probably possible.
- The only way to "link" something in Vim is to another *file* using tags. See [`:help tags-and-searches`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#tags%2dand%2dsearches). Perhaps this feature can be abused into opening web pages, I don't suggest that you try.

In short, you're trying to use Vim for a task it wasn't really designed to do, so doing that will be hard and ugly, if possible at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't require a link that can be "clicked" with a mouse and don't mind having some extra text showing you can use the utl (universal text link) plugin.  Get the details at https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=293.  It is old, but still works for me.  To link to google for instance the text would have < url:www.google.com > in the text.  To use the link, move your cursor somewhere on or between the brackets and input \gu from command mode.  This will cause your browser to go to Google's site. Of course there is some setup in the utl_rc.vim file to point it at your browser.

I should also note that you can use this to move between text files, or within a file as well.  The details are at the link I gave above.